SwiftUI memory leak when using nested sheets and presentationBackground
I have two nested sheets in my app which has been working great. However, when I tried to set the background of one of the sheets the app suddenly starts eating memory and crashes within a few seconds. This happens on iOS 17.0 through 17.5 when using nested sheets with both presentationBackground and presentationBackgroundInteraction. If either of these are removed the app works find. Is there something wrong with the following approach or is this a bug in SwiftUI?
// Crashes after a few seconds
struct CrashingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("-")
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                Text("-")
                    .presentationBackground(.thickMaterial)
                    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .large))
                    .sheet(isPresented: .constant(false)) {
                        Text("-")
                    }
            }
    }
}

// Works fine
struct NonCrashingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("-")
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                Text("-")
                    .presentationBackground(.thickMaterial)
                    // .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .large))
                    .sheet(isPresented: .constant(false)) {
                        Text("-")
                    }
            }
    }
}

The same error occurs when using presentationDetents.

Sheets especially nested sheets have never been SwiftUIs strong suit. You can wait until next week and see if iOS 18 brings any improvements or make a UIKit wrapper

I believe this is fixed in iOS 18.0.

Fixed: When linking against iOS 18 SDKs, SwiftUI prevents cycles in .sheet presentations caused by presentations preferences (e.g. presentationDetents or presentationBackground) that depend on the size of the sheet. In some cases prior to iOS 18, these cycles might settle independently after some oscillation. (117699610)
iOS 18 Release Notes

From my testing the sole culprit is .presentationBackground(...) even without .presentationBackgroundInteraction(...) it would crash.  Based on the release notes though, it it's hard to say which preferences cause the issue, and with certain combinations, it may or may not resolve the cycle itself. In order to be safe, you can use:
.popover(isPresented: $isShowingPopover) {
    if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
        InkingToolTypeSettingsView(inkingTool: inkingTool)
            .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
            .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
    } else {
        InkingToolTypeSettingsView(inkingTool: inkingTool)
    }
}

